# Can I inject the WebApplicationContext of my Spring MVC servlet into a DelegatingFilterProxy?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am creating an OAuth authorization server that uses Spring Security as my security layer around parts of my servlet. An essential part of this is using the `DelegatingFilterProxy` to map to the *springSecurityFilterChain* bean, which requires a `WebApplicationContext` instance.

The standard solution is to include a `ContextLoaderListener` with associated *contextConfigLocation* configuration. But that entails creating a separate configuration for the root `WebApplicationContext`, needlessly complicating matters in my opinion.

According to the Spring MVC documentation, every `DispatcherServlet` has it's own `WebApplicationContext` instance. What's more, from perusing the code of `DelegatingFilterProxy`, it should be possible to inject a `WebApplicationContext` instance at construction time.

So my question is: **Can I set the DispatcherServlet WebApplicationContext as the instance for DelegatingFilterProxy?**

Here is the relevant configuration I have currently:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <!-- Enable Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>oauth</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>oauth</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- ... Spring MVC config ... -->

    <!-- Spring Security OAuth Config -->
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails"
                                token-services-ref="tokenServices"
                                token-endpoint-url="/api/token">
        <oauth:refresh-token/>
        <oauth:client-credentials/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <!-- ... loads more OAuth config ... -->

</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DispatcherServlet` (as any subclass of `FrameworkServlet`) will publish its `WebApplicationContext` in the `ServletContext` using the attribure name: `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.<servlet-name>`.

At the same time `DelegatingFilterProxy` can be told not to use the root `WebApplicationContext` but another one stored in the `ServletContext` by setting its `contextAttribute` parameter.

In your case the required config would be:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.oauth </param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

See more about how `DelegatingFilterProxy` looks up the `WebApplicationContext` in the javadoc of [`findWebApplicationContext()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html#findWebApplicationContext%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for this! I knew about contextAttribute but I could find no documentation for it or the values it takes.